# How to prove that a number never has as many divisors as its value? Other than $1$ and $2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For example, $3$ only has $2$ divisors

$4$ only has $3$ divisors

$5$ only has $2$ divisors

Seems intuitive, but is there a formal proof for this?

Comment: You just need to find one $k$ such that $1 < k < n$ and $k \nmid n$. There's one formula that works for all $n > 2$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Formula? Which one?

Comment: $2$ doesn't divide $3,$ $3$ doesn't divide $4,$ ...

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If $n>2$ have as many divisiors as its values, it means factors of $n$ are $1,\ldots, n$.

In particular $n-1|n$.

This means $n-1$ is both a factor of $n-1$ and $n$ but we have $$n-1 > gcd(n,n-1)=1$$ which is a contradiction.